# Writing web application GUI in a mix of plain-GWT and smart-GWT?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I started working on projects in GWT last month. It was all well until I needed drag and drop(DND). After trying gwt-dnd library like everyone else I got infatuated by smart-gwt widgets. But everywhere I read that its a very thin wrapper over Javascript. But I've still decided to go with it. I have some general questions regarding GWT.

- Is it okay to write the GUI in a mix of plain-GWT and smart-gwt ?
- Can I implement drag and drop only with plain-GWT without the help of external libraries?
- Should I write the smart-GWT like widgets in plain-GWT myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No you shouldn't and neither is proposed from the smartgwt creators, There are some tweaks that can make it work, but it is at a per case base ...
- You could try to achieve this, especially with the latest 2.5 version and its Elemental library.
- Depends what you need and the resources you have for the task. You could make look-like lighter elements macthing the smartgwt ones, but it can be tricky if you are looking after operations like filtering etc. Bottom line is, you wouldn't be considering the smartgwt or any other similar library, if you had the time and resources to develop its widgets.